Google DV360 Reporting - Error while fetching performance metrics
I am trying to extract and download reports from DV360 API using python. I have gone through the documentation https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/get-started/send-request ,but not able to fetch the performance metrics like impressions,clicks,revenue. I have tried the below code,
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/display-video']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'client_secret.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES
)

service = build('displayvideo', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

def create_report_query(filters=None):
    query_body = {
        "params": {
            "type": "STANDARD",
            "groupBys": [
                "FILTER_ADVERTISER_NAME",
                "FILTER_ADVERTISER",
                "FILTER_ADVERTISER_CURRENCY",
                "FILTER_INSERTION_ORDER_NAME",
                "FILTER_INSERTION_ORDER",
                "FILTER_LINE_ITEM_NAME",
                "FILTER_LINE_ITEM",
            ],
            "filters": filters if filters else [],
            "metrics": [
                "METRIC_IMPRESSIONS",
                "METRIC_BILLABLE_IMPRESSIONS",
                "METRIC_CLICKS",
                "METRIC_CTR",
                "METRIC_TOTAL_CONVERSIONS",
                "METRIC_LAST_CLICKS",
                "METRIC_LAST_IMPRESSIONS",
                "METRIC_REVENUE_ADVERTISER",
                "METRIC_MEDIA_COST_ADVERTISER",
            ],
        }
    }
    return query_body

def run_query(service, advertiser_id, query_body):
    request = service.reports().createquery(advertiserId=advertiser_id, body=query_body)
    response = request.execute()
    print("Report created:", response)
    return response

def download_report(service, report_id):
    # Assuming the report is ready and downloadable as CSV
    request = service.reports().getfile(reportId=report_id, fileId=0)
    response = request.execute()
    with open("report.csv", "wb") as f:
        f.write(response)
    print("Report downloaded as 'report.csv'")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace with your Advertiser ID
    ADVERTISER_ID = "your_advertiser_id_here"
    
    query_body = create_report_query()
    
    report_response = run_query(service, ADVERTISER_ID, query_body)
    
    report_id = report_response.get("reportId")
    
    if report_id:
        download_report(service, report_id)

for request = service.reports().createquery(advertiserId=advertiser_id, body=query_body) I'm receiving the following error as AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'reports'
Can anyone please help me to get this? Is there a way to fetch these metrics using DV360 API.

The method you are calling to create report is not correct. In order to create report in DV360 you need to call create method of query as below.
response = service.queries().create(body=body).execute()
print(response.get('queryId'))

Checkout the example as shown in this guide and reference document for create method.
